# Log file in struts2

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2, web

I am maintaining a portal having no documentation.

Technology used are Struts2,iBatis,JQuery,jsp on tomact(Linux) and others.

Log4j.properties define log file :

```
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.home}/webapps/logfile.log
```

But I am not getting logfile.log at the defined path.I am getting another name(say test.log) at this path.

What i understand that log4j file is not used and test.log is created through code.
But i am not able to find out where these properties is defined through code.

test.log logs xWorks related logs.

Example Text of log:

```
2012-07-09 00:00:58,894 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase - Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1341772258894 sessioncount 2
2012-07-09 00:00:58,895 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase - End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 1 expired sessions: 0
2012-07-09 00:01:59,111 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase - Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1341772319111 sessioncount 2
2012-07-09 00:01:59,112 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase - End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 1 expired sessions: 0
2012-07-09 00:02:59,336
```

---

Could any body tell me where these logs are defined.I searched through code but did not find anything.Also where is struts system logs are defined?
There is no application specific logging interceptor.

Any guess or idea?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

They should be defined in your exploded web app dir assuming it's deployed as a WAR file.

/path/to/server/**webapps/{appname}/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties**

In that file is where you define paths to log output.  For example, I have a log file in:

**/path/to/server/logs/{log file}** and it is configured like this:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

log4j.appender.error=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.error.file=${catalina.base}/logs/gc-error.log
log4j.appender.error.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.error.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.error.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d (%c) - <%m>%n
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.But issue is,the defined file in log4j.properties is not created but some different file is created.Is there any other place in struts frame work or tomacat where we can create file for logging.